# There is no metadata information for provider 'npgsql'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz

Below is my config for connection to database using Quartz using Asp.net Core.

```
 ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
                ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz",
                ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
                ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=202.131.112.197;Port=5434;Database=Quartzdb;User Id=postgres;Password=Cygnet@123;",
                ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "Npgsql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your version of Quartz but I am using  2.2.4 with .net 4.5 and

```
["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "Npgsql-20"
```

is working for me.

for details you can check https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html

Also you can use bindingRedirect at your app or web config file like ;

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.7.0" newVersion="3.2.7.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

with binding redirect you can use the desired version of Npgsql

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `Npgsql` nuget to the project. After that it worked just fine